# Add some text to an xml package - aspdotnetstorefront

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am working on a an aspdotnetstorefront xml template and totally out of my depth. This application uses xml packages and I have figured out how to style the contents of different  sections. I'm stuck on on an extremely simple thing: I just need to add a couple headings to the output, which will go outside the template tags. I've tried placing it between CDATA tags as some are recommending, but everything I try breaks the page.

In rough outline, I need:

Add "Categories"

-iteration of categories

Add "Featured Products"

-iteration of products

Thank you!

Comment: go ahead and add the code from your most recent attempt to to the question (if you can't figure out the formatting, do your best and someone will come along to help format it).  Once your code is added the quality of your possible answers increases dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be the fact that you are attempting to enter values outside a set of template tags. Since you are producing some type of iteration, you will most likely want to be working within a template.

XML Packages should have no problem handling valid HTML. In other words, entering text could be treated just like you would in an HTML document. Just remember to close all your tags. You will also find that HTML codes will have to be used, for certain special characters.

If you are still having issues, feel free to share your xml package code, so I can have a look.